# "There'll be magic" -- Foreshadowing in For the First Time in Forever?

Tags: frozen

In *For the First Time in Forever*, Anna sings "*for the first time in forever / there'll be magic, there'll be fun"*. ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BulXil2ROy4#t=103))

**Is this foreshadowing of Elsa's display of magic later that night?** After all, it is the first time since they were young children that there's magic. ;)

Comment: Personally, I'd guess it's the more general "Disney Magic" type of concept. Not actual, real, Harry Potter-type magic.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any actual answer to this, but I'm with Catija, I feel this was just a mention of "Disney Magic" like when you're excited for something, you say "this will be a magical evening".  You're not saying you're going to cast spells, you're just saying it's going to be fun, a lot of good is going to happen, etc.  I personally don't think it'd make any sense for Anna to even know if her sister was going to perform magic since they don't really talk or have any real contact with each other at that point in the movie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any foreboding in the scene.

[Multiple](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=301420227) [interviews](http://www.thewire.com/entertainment/2013/11/explaining-five-songs-frozen/355512/) show that the purpose of the song was to both display a quirky, fun Disney princess and showcase Kristen Bell's "modern. funny girl sensibility" (to quote from the second article).

Consider this segment of an interview with Robert Lopez and Kristen Anderson-Lopez, the songwriters, from the first article linked:

> **Interviewer** So, you know, it's a fun song. There's a line in it that is definitely
>   I think not for children but for adults...
>   And the line is, don't know if I'm elated or gassy. But I'm
>   somewhere in that zone.
>
> **Anderson-Lopez**: ...Don't know if I'm elated or gassy. But I'm
>   somewhere in that zone. Again, we were trying to say this is a Disney
>   Princess who gets gas. This is a Disney princess who is human with a
>   human body and we're going to spend some time with a real girl.

In other words, the emphasis was heavily on taking the *usual* stereotypical Disney princess and making her seem fun, quirky, girl-next-door-esque.

The line about magic was simply a young woman expressing her joy at the gates to the castle *finally* being opened after all these years.

It *does* of course accurately forebode what follows, but whether this was intentional (i.e. chosen by Disney), slipped in (i.e. by the songwriters) or just a complete coincidence, is something we'll likely never have an answer for.

However, given the context of the song, it seems very likely it's just a random lyric and isn't tied to any sense of revelation over Elsa's actions.